# twitter json - strange error

Tags: c#, json

I have the method below to parse data from the twitter search, strange thing is this method works fine in one of my forms but in my main form it returns the exception:

> Exception: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictonary" does not
>   contain a definition for "text"

The two forms are almost identical and i cannot understand why i cant get the code to work.. anyone got any ideas?

Below is the method:

```
public static HashSet<string> searchTwitterJson(string searchTerm)
    {
        HashSet<string> resultsFound = new HashSet<string>();


        if (searchTerm != "")
        {
            string v = searchTerm.Replace("\"", "%22");
            string keyword = v.Trim();
            string keywordet = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(keyword);


            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/phoenix_search.phoenix?q=" + keywordet + "&headers[X-Twitter-Polling]=true&headers[X-PHX]=true&since_id=203194965877194752&include_entities=1&include_available_features=1&contributor_details=true&mode=relevance&query_source=unknown");
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                string limit = response.Headers["X-RateLimit-Remaining"];


                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                serializer.RegisterConverters((new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() }));
                dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(responseString, typeof(object)) as dynamic;

                foreach (var objects in obj.statuses) 
                {
                    if ((objects.text != null) && (objects.user.screen_name != null) && (objects.id_str != null))
                    {
                        Match m = Regex.Match(objects.text, @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/\S\w[\w- ;,./?%&=]\S*)?");


                        if (!m.Success)
                        {
                            string loggaD = objects.user.screen_name.ToString() + "/" + objects.id_str.ToString();
                            resultsFound.Add(loggaD);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No searchterm");
        }

        return resultsFound;
    }
```

Part of the JSON i am receiving:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "statuses": [{
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "id_str": "203239104421445632",
        "truncated": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "created_at": "Thu May 17 21:42:33 +0000 2012",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "favorited": false,
        "geo": null,
        "user": {
            "screen_name": "YouthNorrort"
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "source": "\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003EFacebook\u003C\/a\u003E",
        "place": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 203239104421445632,
        "retweeted": false,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "text": "Hejsan igen!\nvi \u00e4r ledsna att meddela er, men inf\u00f6r imorgon s\u00e5 finns det inga bilar, allts\u00e5 inte heller plats f\u00f6r... http:\/\/t.co\/pMKoOz7o",
        "result_category": "recent"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the response doesn't contain an item at the node under "statuses".[i]. Check the JSON which is being returned, and if it doesn't have it, then you can't try to access it.

```
{
    "statuses":
    [
        {
            "text": ...,
            "user: { "screen_name": ... }
        }
    ]
}
```

The code:

```
 if ((objects.text != null) && (objects.user.screen_name != null) && (objects.id_str != null))
```

**Update**: based on your JSON example, it works fine (see below). Do all elements in the statuses array contain the "text" member?

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string json = @"{
""error"": null,
""statuses"": [{
    ""in_reply_to_status_id_str"": null,
    ""id_str"": ""203239104421445632"",
    ""truncated"": false,
    ""possibly_sensitive"": false,
    ""created_at"": ""Thu May 17 21:42:33 +0000 2012"",
    ""in_reply_to_user_id_str"": null,
    ""contributors"": null,
    ""favorited"": false,
    ""geo"": null,
    ""user"": {
        ""screen_name"": ""YouthNorrort""
    },
    ""in_reply_to_screen_name"": null,
    ""coordinates"": null,
    ""retweet_count"": 0,
    ""source"": ""\u003Ca href=\""http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\"" rel=\""nofollow\""\u003EFacebook\u003C\/a\u003E"",
    ""place"": null,
    ""in_reply_to_status_id"": null,
    ""id"": 203239104421445632,
    ""retweeted"": false,
    ""in_reply_to_user_id"": null,
    ""text"": ""Hejsan igen!\nvi \u00e4r ledsna att meddela er, men inf\u00f6r imorgon s\u00e5 finns det inga bilar, allts\u00e5 inte heller plats f\u00f6r... http:\/\/t.co\/pMKoOz7o"",
    ""result_category"": ""recent""
}]}";
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
        dynamic obj = jss.Deserialize(json, typeof(object)) as dynamic;

        foreach (var objects in obj.statuses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(objects.GetType());
            if (objects.ContainsKey("text"))
            {
                if ((objects.text != null) && (objects.user.screen_name != null) && (objects.id_str != null))
                {
                    Match m = Regex.Match(objects.text, @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/\S\w[\w- ;,./?%&=]\S*)?");

                    if (!m.Success)
                    {
                        string loggaD = objects.user.screen_name.ToString() + "/" + objects.id_str.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(loggaD);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the code for TryInvokeMember:

```
            public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
            {
                if (binder.Name == "ContainsKey")
                {
                    result = _dictionary.ContainsKey(args[0] as string);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The super strange thing is that Fiddler shows this in the beginning: {"error":null,"statuses":[{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":....

Comment: and i see text and the others there as well

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're receiving?

Comment: updated it, i removed some stuff and only posted one.. they send a lot of data :)

Comment: hmm maybe all do not contain the text member, is there a way i can just skip those and print the rest?

Comment: I assume you're using the DynamicJsonConverter shown at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3142495/751090; if this is the case, you need to first implement `TryInvokeMember` on the DynamicJsonObject class, then you can use the ContainsKey method prior to accessing the member. See updated answer.